# First 5 records in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am using show/hide items in the properties of a barchart for getting top 10 records, unfortunately table has same value for more than 40 records so chart is displaying all 40 even restricting top 10. I want to pick first five among the 40 records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you are trying to display top 10 records (regardless of the agregation method or criteria) then use the row number (rowid) for your rule column and set the rule type as bottom 5 to show top 5 records.